# Reset EditorGridPanel column values

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm looking for way how to on button click reset all fields in EditorGridPanel in one column

There is a code of column

```
....
{
    id: 'field_id',
    header: "Amount [ton/ha]",
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'amountId',
    width: 150,
    summaryType: 'sum',
    summaryRenderer: function(v){
        return v +' [ton/ha]';
    },                 
    editor: new Ext.form.NumberField({
        allowBlank: false,
        allowNegative: false,
        style: 'text-align:left'
    }),
    groupName: 'Amount'
},
.....
```

So far this is going to be editable, what you can see from the code and it works perfect, just want to add possibility to reset all values, is it posible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Store` and even `Record` have methods for rejecting and commiting changes. I haven't used them but I believe it would be like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore().getAt(0).rejectChanges();
```

and for all rows in the store:

```
Ext.getCmp('myGrid').getStore().rejectChanges();
```